# How can I add columns as categories in a bar chart using Dimple.js?

Tags: d3.js, data-visualization, dimple.js

I want to plot a bar chart using dimple.js in which I want to plot the portion of users in different categories. Each category is a column in my dataset.

My data looks like this:

[image: Table with sample data]

I would like to have a chart in which I had a bar for each platform and each column `Q14_*`.

I understand that platform should be a series:

```
myChart.addSeries("Platform", dimple.plot.area);
```

However, I don't know how to do add the bars for each column.
How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried doing the same thing a while ago and decided to reconstruct the data. But I'm not sure if this is the best solution possible. Anyway, this is my solution:

1. Reconstruct the data to have the following columns:

   - platform (values: Android, Apple)
   - portion (values: the numerical proportion)
   - quarter (values: Q14_1, Q14_2 ....)
2. Use proportional axis for the platform column to show the proportion: [addPctAxis](https://github.com/PMSI-AlignAlytics/dimple/wiki/dimple.chart#addPctAxis),
3. Use the quarter as a category axis for X.
4. Use the portion column as the series.

Then the code should look like:

```
myChart.addCategoryAxis("x", "quarter");
myChart.addPctAxis("y", "platform");
myChart.addSeries("portion", dimple.plot.bar);
```

Also, there several examples using `addPctAxis` you can learn from which are pretty similar to what you are asking. You might want to have a look:

- [vertical proportional bars](http://dimplejs.org/examples_viewer.html?id=bars_vertical_stacked_100pct)
- [horizontal proportional bars](http://dimplejs.org/examples_viewer.html?id=bars_horizontal_stacked_100pct)
- [more advanced - two proportional bar axes](http://dimplejs.org/examples_viewer.html?id=bars_horizontal_mekko)